# php how to access object properties with hyphen?

Tags: php, json

The json format.

```
{
  "message-count":"1",
  "messages":[
    {
    "status":"returnCode",
    "error-text":"error-message"
    }
  ]
}
```

In php, I successfully get "status" value with `$response->messages[0]->status` 
But when I wanted to access "error-text" properties, the code `$response->messages[0]->error-text` gives me error.
How to access object properties with hyphen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `{}` syntax:

```
echo $response->messages[0]->{'error-text'};
```

Answer (score 8):

here is the way!

```
$object->{"message-count"};
$response->messages[0]->{'error-text'};
```

hope this helps

---

any string (bytes sequence) can be used as a class field

```
$object->{"123"} = 10; // numbers
$object->{"{a}"} = 10; // special characters
$object->{"òòèè"} = 10; // non ascii characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use standard PHP feature - accessing variables within curly braces:

```
class t {}
$a = new t();
$a->{"o-o"} = 1;
echo $a->{"o-o"};
```

So, you need to write $response->messages[0]->{"error-text"}.